# Use JQuery to fix element from bottom of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found plenty of examples of fixing an element's top relative to the window. How do I fix an element X pixels from the bottom of the window? Simply changing 'top' to 'bottom' does not work (for example,if the element's height is more than the window height)

From the top:

```
var pixels = 10;
var $elemPosition = $element.position();
var $elementH = $element.height();
var $windowH = $(window).height();
var $bottom = $element.offset().top + $element.height();

if ($(window).scrollTop() + pixels >= $elemPosition.top) {
    $element.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': pixels + 'px'
    });
} else {
    $element.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '0px'
    });
}
```

Solved it! Solution I came up with:

```
if (($windowH + $(window).scrollTop() - $bottom - pixels) >= 0) {
    $element.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': ($windowH - $element.height() - pixels) + 'px',
        'width': $eW + 'px',
        'height': $eH + 'px'
    });
} else {
    $element.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '0px'
    });
}
```

Comment: `bottom` instead of `top` maybe ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the height of the element has to be taken into consideration

Comment: then capture the height of the element with `$element.height();` and apply it to the `bottom` value :)

Comment: the window scroll function has to be tweaked to scroll 10px past the bottom of the element then change the element's position to fixed and bottom to 10

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS `bottom` property instead of the `top` property.

```
$element.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'bottom': pixels + 'px'
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, especially when there's another element with a height greater than the element I want to fix (maybe because the element is in the same container as the larger element?) I solved the problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments and demand :

> for example,if the element's height is more than the window height

You wants [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/y2q56qf0/9/) ?

> JS

```
$element = $("#element");
function setPosition(){
    var pixels = 10;
  var $elementH = $element.height();
  var $windowH = $(window).height();

  if ($windowH > $elementH) {
      $element.css({
          'position': 'fixed',
          'bottom': pixels + 'px'
      });
  } else {
      $element.css({
          'position': 'relative',
          'bottom': '0px'
      });
  }
}

$(function(){
    setPosition();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    setPosition();
  });
});
```

If you try to change the `height` of the element to `700px` for instance, you'll see he gets relative position.

Comment: That doesn't work. The element in your solution doesn't scroll then fix, it's always fixed. I solved problem. See above for the solution

Comment: Ok, it was a misunderstanding then. I thought you wanted to switch the position of the element depending of the scroll of the window.